# C# implementation of Ascii Minimum Delete Distance

Tags: c#, algorithm

How do you implement the ASCII Minimum Delete Distance in C#?

See description here with a Python solution.
[Deletion distance between 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490091/deletion-distance-between-2-strings)

Answer (score 0):

I derived the C# solution from this Java solution.
https://leetcode.com/articles/minimum-ascii-delete-sum-for-two-strings/#

```
static void TestAscMinDelDist()
{
  List<string[]> l = new List<string[]> {
    new string[]{"cat", "at", "99"},
    new string[]{"aunt","ant", "117"},
    new string[]{"sea", "eat", "231"},
    new string[]{"boat", "got", "298"},,
    new string[]{"toradol", "tramadol", "317"},
    new string[]{"tattoo","platoon", "562"},
    new string[]{"delete", "leet", "403"},
    new string[]{"flomax", "volmax", "436"},
    new string[]{"clozapine", "olanzapine", "522"},
    new string[]{"Sam", "Samantha", "524"},
    new string[]{"kitten", "sitting", "531" },
    new string[]{"sloughs", "thought", "674"}, };

  foreach (string[] a in l) {
    CalcPrint(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    CalcPrint(a[1], a[0], a[2]);
  }
}

static int AsciiMinimumDeleteDistance(String s1, String s2) {
  int s1Len = s1.Length, s2Len = s2.Length;
  int[,] dp = new int[s1Len + 1, s2Len + 1];

  for (int i = s1Len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      dp[i, s2Len] = dp[i + 1, s2Len] + (int)s1[i]; }

  for (int j = s2Len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
      dp[s1Len, j] = dp[s1Len, j+1] + (int)s2[j]; }

  for (int i = s1Len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      for (int j = s2Len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
              dp[i, j] = dp[i+1, j+1];
          } else {
              dp[i, j] = Math.Min(dp[i+1, j] + (int)s1[i],
                                  dp[i, j+1] + (int)s2[j]);
          }
      }
  }
  return dp[0,0];
}

static void CalcPrint(string s1, string s2, string s3)
{
  int cost = AsciiMinimumDeleteDistance(s1, s2);
  string result = cost == int.Parse(s3) ? "Passed" : "Failed: Expected: " + s3;
  Console.WriteLine($"{s1} -> {s2} {cost} \t {result}");
}
```

---

[image]